# On button click i want to display record from database laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I have a  a a list that has a foreach loop.

```
<ul>
    <?php $i = 0?>
    @foreach ($cards as $card)
        <li id="{{$i}}"><a href="#">{{$card->title}}</a></li>
        <?php $i = $i + 1; ?>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Based on id i want to display card->id when i click the link I want to display that specific cards's id.

```
<script>
    var myvar='<?php echo json_encode($cards);?>';

    alert(myvar);
    for(var i=0;i<myvar.length;i++)
    {
        $( "#"+i ).click(function() {
            alert( myvar );
        })
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Where you want to display the name? are you able to use javascript/jquery in your project? Please try to add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I should use jquery on my project yes ! I need it displayed next to a simple div.

Comment: Ok try to add your controler code and your full view code including the `div` where the name should be displayed.

Comment: You mean `@foreach(User:all() as $user)
{{ $user->id }}`

Comment: but i should fetch the name for every user from my database!

Comment: yes Chibueze Opata

Comment: It's not a big deal. You should see the error if you look more closely. Make sure your debug config is set to true or your environment is properly set.

Comment: ok but I do not know where to begin with jquery so that was not a mistake I fixed it as to not get confused.

Comment: My question is how to show the database record that contains the name when I click on the link.

Comment: OK, then your question should contain the tags jQuery and title is a bit misleading as well. Something like 'how to display on click' is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you fetch already the data in your `foreach` loop we will just hide the user name inside the following div of every link then we will show it when the user click on the link, so we don't have to make connection to the database every time the user click.

You have to add class to your link `my-link` and add div where you want to show the name `.name` to your view :

**view code:**

```
<ul>
    @foreach(User:all() as $user)
        <li>
             <a href='' class='my-link'>{{$user->id}}</a>
             <div class='name' style="display: none">{{$user->name}}</div>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

The add javascript code that attach the click event to the buttons with class `my-btn`.

**JS code :**

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', 'my-link', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         $(this).parent().find('.name').show();
    })
})
```

**NOTE :** make sure you're including jquery library in your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to show user->name instead of foreach I need to load the object user to a javascript object and loop throught it.but I don't know how.

Comment: outside the foreach loop that is the problem.